# Change image of a scrollview or replace the array of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a problem with changing images in the scrollview, the scrollview problem is that depending on the action that makes me have to change the image that contains other, as I do not change the picture or the array of images, I need help, thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray *imgNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cooper.png", @"cabrio.png",@"country.png", nil];


   NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempImageView;

    for(NSString *name in imgNames) {

        tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        tempImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];   
    }

    CGSize pageSize = scrollView.frame.size;

    NSUInteger page = 0;

    for(UIView *view in imgArray) {

        [scrollView addSubview:view];

        view.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 10, 0, pageSize.width - 20, pageSize.height);
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);

}

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {


    NSMutableArray *imgNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello.png", @"bye.png",@"trues.png", nil];


   NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempImageView;

    for(NSString *name in imgNames) {

        tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        tempImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];   
    }

    CGSize pageSize = scrollView.frame.size;

    NSUInteger page = 0;

    for(UIView *view in imgArray) {

        [scrollView addSubview:view];

        view.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 10, 0, pageSize.width - 20, pageSize.height);
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set the image alone if UIImageView is already allocated in viewDidLoad like,

```
for(UIImageView *view in imgArray) {

     view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgNames objectAtIndex:[imgArray indexOfObject:view]]]
}
```

Comment: thanks!! a question, you know how to tell the scroolview Begin by showing you x position and not the first?

Comment: if I have an array with 3 images: image 1, image2, image3, when it comes to the screen where I have the scrollview, starting this image1 show me and I want for example to show me image2 start, but respecting the order of the array when are input

Comment: if you want to show image2 initially, just set the setContentOffset property of scrollview.

Comment: else if u want to display image order as image2, image3, image1 means rearrange accordingly..